# Length of dynamic array returned by function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have a function that accepts some variables and returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of integers. Pretty quickly I discovered that there was a problem; outside of the function, I do not know how many elements are in the array (and it would be too expensive to determine this by examining the input).

So, I define

```
typedef struct Pair {
    int* ptr;
    int length;
} Pair;
```

and modify the function to return this struct. This works as intended, though I have concerns. I have never seen anything like this done. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: If you know the size of the elements in an array sizeof(array)/element_size will give you the number of elements

Comment: @Tibrogargan You can't use that system for arrays passed as function arguments or return values, as the array decays to a pointer. And nor can you use it on dynamically allocated arrays, like `int* array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);`.

Comment: Seems like a valid solution to me. Length should probably be `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t`, but it depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, your method of returning a structure will work, and it is safe. Whether or not it is the 'correct' approach is really a matter of opinion; another way would be to return the array and its size in arguments given as pointers (actually, a pointer-to-pointer for the array itself):

```c
int CreateArray(int** array, size_t* size)
{
    size_t n = 42; // Or whatever size is required.
    // .. Some code here that determines the 'n' value required
    int* data = malloc(sizeof(int) * n); // Create the array
    if (data != NULL) { // Success...
        *array = data; // Set first argument to POINT to the new array
        *size = n;     // and the second to point to its size
        return 1;      // Return "1" to indicate success
    }
    else { // Error: set size to zero and return "0" error code...
        *array = NULL;
        *size = 0;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You could then call this function like this:

```c
int main()
{
    int* MyArray;
    size_t ArraySize;
    int status = CreateArray(&MyArray, &ArraySize); // Pass the ADDRESS of the pointer and of the size.
    if (!status) {
        // Error message, or whatever!
        return 1;
    }
    // You can now do stuff with MyArray, knowing that its size is in ArraySize
    //...
    free(MyArray); //Don't forget to free the memory when you're done with it!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd say OP's solution is generally easier to work with. I'd prefer it over out-parameters.

Comment: @Ayxan Actually, I agree with you, which is why I opened with stating that their method is OK. The alternative I proffered is, as you say, more 'clumsy' to work with, but it is used by a number of platforms, such as the `WinAPI` for calls that return an allocated buffer.

Answer (score 4):

It's *correct* in that the only way an allocating function can return the size of of the allocation is by returning that information.  It's not usual and customary, though.

Normally, the caller has some idea of how many elements there are likely to be, and allocates accordingly.  Examples include **scanf**(3), the array of matched expressions in **regexec**(3), and the buffer array for **readv**(2).  Those function are passed the array size, and return the number filled.

Functions that allocate arrays are relatively rare.  Of those that do in the standard library, I can't think of one that returns a structure like yours.  Normally, either the pointer or the count is returned by value, and the other by reference.  **scandir**(3), for instance, allocates an an array of character pointers.  The number of elements is the return value of the function.  The location of the array is written to pointer whose address is passed as an argument (`char ***`).

Another technique is not to return the memory, but instead provide iteration and free functions.  Examples include **opendir**(3) and **getpwent**(3).

Of course, the C standard library was developed in an era when C functions couldn't return whole structures.  Maybe they'd look different if that hadn't been the case.  That said, the dominant idiom of *caller allocates* suggests you might want to consider carefully whether you really like your function as designed.

Comment: [glob](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html) is part of the Posix standard library, so I guess it doesn't quite count. (And it returns the vector as an out parameter, not as the return value.)